# Komascript ToC in Urdu: Formatting chapterentry not working

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, fontspec, polyglossia

Koma-script works with Urdu using fontspec and polyglossia. However, modifying the chapter entry does not seem to work.

As I can only use AutoFakeBold with the Awami font I'm using, I use it extremely sparingly, although I can't afford to dispose with it fully. Thus I've changed the disposition to switch bold off for headings. That works. However, the chapter entry in the ToC is still bold. It cannot be changed using the chapterentry command either (in the MWE set to \tiny to make it more obvious that no change is taking place).

Could this be due to the fact that I have not set Awami as the main font, whilst Koma-Script is using the main font for the ToC? I can't test this, as setting Urdu fonts as the mainfont in combination with polyglossia has never worked for me. (The reason would interest me extremely though.)

Is there a workaround or/and a way to use the Urdu font as the mainfont (if that is the problem)?

(Content taken from https://ur.wikipedia.org/wiki/%DB%81%D9%86%D8%AF%DB%8C_%D8%B2%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,openany]{scrbook}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\urdufont}
\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\urdufont\tiny}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}
\newfontfamily\urdufont{Awami Nastaliq}[AutoFakeBold=4.0,Scale=.88,Renderer=Graphite,RawFeature={Short forms=All}]

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[RTLdocument,extrafootnotefeatures]{bidi}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=western]{urdu}
\setotherlanguage[variant=uk]{english} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addchap{ہندوستانی}
جب انگریز برصغیر میں آئے تو ان کو جس زبان سے واسطہ پڑا وہ اردو تھی جسے وہ ہندوستانی کہتے تھے۔ انہوں نے ابتدا میں عدالتی اور دفتری زبان فارسی رکھی۔ مگر اردو کی مقبولیت کو دیکھتے ہوئے اردو کو رائج کرنے کا فیصلہ کیا۔ کیوں کہ یہ طبقہ اسی کو اپنی بول چال میں استعمال کرتا تھا۔ اس میں مذہب کی بنا پر کوئی امتیاز نہیں تھا اور ہندو و مسلمان سب اسے لکھتے اور پڑھتے تھے۔ جسے انگریز ہندوستانی Hubdistanee کہتے تھے۔   
\addchap{ابتدا}
1800ء میں فورٹ ولیم کی ڈاغ بیل ڈالی گئی کہ برطانوی اہلکاروں کو اردو زبان سیکھائی یا جائے۔ جان گلکرسٹ جس نے اردو کی بیش بہا خدمت کی ہے نے 1803ء میں للوجی نے کو پریم ساگر دیوناگری رسم الخط میں لکھنے کو کہا گیا اور اس نے فورٹ ولیم کے احاطے میں ایک نئی زبان کی بنیاد رکھ دی۔ فورٹ ولیم کے باہر بھی کچھ ہندو کھڑی بولی میں دیوناگری میں لکھنے کا تجربہ کرنے لگے اور عربی فارسی کے الفاظ نکال کر سنسکرت کے الفاظ استعمال کرنے لگے۔ سنیتی کمار چٹرجی نے اس زبان کو سنسکرتی ہندی کا نام دیا۔
\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of the ToC:

[image]

Comment: You should add a screenshot,  it is a bit unclear what you get.

Comment: it is a bug in bidi which had already been reported in may: https://github.com/persiantex/bidi/issues/14. A work around could be `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\scr@tso@chapter@entryformat{\usekomafont{chapterentry}}`, but looking at the bugs there could be more incompabilities to scrbook hidden in bidi. Also bidi will break with the next latex version, if it is not adapted before, see https://github.com/persiantex/bidi/issues/18. So consider to use lualatex + the bidi options of babel instead of bidi and polyglossia.

Comment: Your suggestion works well. I had always understood polyglossia to be a better package than babel. Is that no longer the case?

Comment: in this case it is not really a polyglossia problem, but of bidi. But beside this I don't think that polyglossia is better than babel. At some time it supported more languages, but babel has now catched up for most, if not for all languages, and also correctly supports the new unicode engines. But I'm biased: babel is developed in the latex github, and I'm a member of the latex team.

Comment: Does it make sense to add your comment as a proper answer? It works for texlive 2020. I haven't gotten around to trying out your lualatex suggestion, otherwise I would have liked to have confirmed it for others checking this out. I'm definitely leaning that way. But font issues with lualatex are making me hesitant. In any case, Xetex does not seem to work with babel und Urdu in texlive 2020.